# Not allowed to point to this.state.anything at any time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components

I can set the state with the function `setState` I can also declare it in the contructor.

that's it.

typescript does not allow me to access it no matter where I put it I need to access it in my methods and in my html but `this.state.mything` give the error :

> TS2339: Property 'mything' does not exist on type 'Readonly{}>'.

what do I do?

there are no such examples online.
everyone uses `this.state.mything` without a hitch seemingly.

```
class Component extends React.Component {

  constructor(props: any) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { mything: ''} 
  }

  render() {
      return(
         <div>
            {this.state.mything} //ERROR
         </div>
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case the state has to be instantiated like so, for good measure this applies to props as well so here is how you instantiate props and state

```
interface Props {
    mything: string
}

interface State {
    mything: string
}

class Component extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props: any) {
     super(props);
     this.state = { mything: ''} 
  }

  render() {
      return(
         <div>
           {this.state.mything}
         </div>

      )
  }
```